# RxJs: Update observables inside a subscription correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I wondered how to update a observable inside a subscription without triggering to many events.

In this example I subscribe to `area: Observable<Area>`, if the area changes I'd like to update the `theme: Observable<Theme>`. `distinctUntilChanged()` should do that the subscription is only triggered if the value has changed, but everytime the `area` gets updated, the amount of `theme` updates increases by one.

```
  observeArea(): void {
    this.area
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) 
    .subscribe(area => {
      this.themeService.updateTheme({primaryColor: area.color}); // should happen only once per area change
    })
  }
```

Is there any "correct" way of doing this, without triggering endless theme updates?

Comment: `area` seems to be an object, if `area` is immutable `distinctUntilChanged` should work properly

Comment: do you just want to observe area.color?

Comment: You have to watch distinctUntilChanged with object comparison, if you're emitting a new object, even if all the values are the same it's a different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the way you are updating the theme.

If you are trying to update the theme by calling `observeArea()` method.

Every time you call the method a new subscription will be created.
Event will be passed to every subscription. So each time you call the method one subscription will be increasing.

**Solution**

1. Use an `async` pipe

```js
area$!: Observable<any>;
observeArea(): void {
  this.area$ = this.area
  .pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(area => this.themeService.updateTheme({primaryColor: area.color});)
   )
}
```

and in html use `area$ | async` to subscribe.
example:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="area$ | async">...</ng-container>
```

2. Else you should unsubscribe every time your subscription completes

```js
observeArea(): void {
    const sub = this.area
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) 
    .subscribe(area => {
      this.themeService.updateTheme({primaryColor: area.color});
      sub.unsubscribe();
    })
  }
```

Better to use `async` pipe.

I believe this solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah thats right, everytime I entered the screen another subscription was created. Ty